# Distinct relations in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Having done only set theory (or more specifically, trying to grasp it) so far, can someone explain what's meant with distinct relations in sets?
For example, assuming I have the sets: $A=\{a, b\}$ and $B=\{c, d, e\}$ and I would want to find out the distinct relations from $A$ to $B$, how would one solve this and what's the meaning behind it?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: The term "distinct relation" has no standard meaning, unless the word "distinct" is just for emphasis and it merely means to list all the relations from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: So basically just A x B?

Comment: Remember that a relation from $A$ to $B$ is merely a subset of $A\times B$.  One example of a relation from $A$ to $B$ is the relation $\{(a,c),(a,d),(a,e)\}$.  Another example is $\{(a,c),(b,d)\}$.  Yet another would be $\emptyset$.  The list goes on.  If you want to actually write them all out, you can follow a simple algorithm to do so, but noone generally bothers, it is easier to refer to the set of all relations from $A$ to $B$ simply as $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$ where $\mathcal{P}(~)$ refers to the powerset.  The *number* of such relations would be $2^{|A|\times |B|}$

Comment: People use relations all the time in their everyday life, we just have specific names for those relations.  For example, let $A$ be the set of English letters $\{a,b,c,d,\dots,z\}$ and let $B$ be the set of English words appearing in the Oxford Dictionary: $B=\{\text{aardvark, abacus, abate},\dots\}$.  Then one example of a relation is the "*is the first letter of*" relation, where $a$ is related to "aardvark" since the first letter of "aardvark" is $a$.  A different relation would be "*is a letter in*" where not only is $a$ related to "aardvark" but so too is $d$ and $v$ etc...

Comment: Some relations are more useful than others, some have nicer properties than others, some are more interesting than others, but again it all boils down to the definitions.  A relation from $A$ to $B$ is simply a subset of $A\times B$.  As you continue studying mathematics, elementary set theory, and functions in particular, you will look specifically at relations which satisfy certain "nice" properties and use those properties to understand more of the structure and implications caused by having said properties.

Comment: I think there is a bit of an abstraction between the practical idea of a relation being a shared concept between two items, and the abstract concept in math of a list of pairs that simply are on or not on a list.  But they are the exact same thing.  If A={fish,penguins,tigers,dogs} and B={worms,hay,fish,people} and the relation is "a eats b" then that is just {(fish,worms),(pengins,fish),(tigers,fish), (tigers,people)}.  That is *one* relation.  There are 65,583 other relations because there are 65,584 (or $2^{16}$) possible lists.